# Test-ComputerSecureChannel - Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password

Tags: windows, networking, active-directory, powershell, netdom

I restored a Win7 image that I know will be out of date.   I then run as administrator powershell from an account that is a member of the local machine administrator group.

All I get is:

```
Test-ComputerSecureChannel : Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.
At line:1 char:27
+ Test-ComputerSecureChannel <<<<  -verbose
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Test-ComputerSecureChannel], AuthenticationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestComputerSecureChannelCommand
```

Or if I provide Credential:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Test-ComputerSecureChannel -Credential domain\administrator
Test-ComputerSecureChannel : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Credential'.
At line:1 char:39
+ Test-ComputerSecureChannel -Credential <<<<  domain\administrator
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Test-ComputerSecureChannel], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestComputerSecureChannelCommand
```

I even tried using `psexec -sid` to run powershell under the `system` account but that gives `same unknown user or bad password` issue.

How is this supposed to work?

Comment: I rejoined the domain and using `nltest` works without access denied (it had said that before rejoining the domain), but the `Test-ComputerSecureChannel` still gives the same logon failure message.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure to remove the computer account from Active Directory. Then rejoin the computer in domain. It will reset the password of the computer account in AD.

Please let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$cred = Get-Credential
Test-ComputerSecureChannel -Credential $cred
```

When running $cred = Get-Credential make sure to enter a domain account that permissions to read computer accounts. Best thing is to be logged on with a domain account.

This cmdlet works much like NetDom.exe. Both NetDom and Test-ComputerSecureChannel use the NetLogon service to perform the actions.